# docusign war file not running

Tags: java, docusignapi, war

i created a war file for code-examples-java in STS (spring tool site), and when i try to run it, it shows this:

> HTTP Status 404 – Not Found Type Status Report
>
> Message The requested resource [/code-examples-java-1.0-SNAPSHOT/] is
> not available
>
> Description The origin server did not find a current representation
> for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one
> exists.

i did not change anything i just get it from github and exported as a war file.
in the IDE it works everything fine, but not in the tomcat.

in the log files it does not appear any error.

Name of the war file is: code-examples-java-1.0-SNAPSHOT

i use Tomcat 9.0.48  and java version 11

Comment: What is the name of the war file you created?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Name of the war file:
code-examples-java-1.0-SNAPSHOT